# Create a tuple for each line by filtering data using regex from a text file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So basically I want to create a function which loads a text file and returns a list of tuples by filtering the required parts using regex.

This text file contains lines in the form of:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf`

And the tuple should be like:

`(25399, "Nov", 2, 21, 25, "exception_hierarchy.pdf")`

Basically it filters out the size, month, day, hour, minute, filename. I can load the file and all but unable to apply regex on this to filter out and then how to return a list of tuples. A piece of help on that particular line will do.

Comment: try using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with [capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: you should really play around with regex on your own, its a useful skill, but here is a lazy solution `'(\d{2,})\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)\s+(.*)'`

Comment: Hi, perhaps this is not an options in your situation, but I think just splitting this line on spaces (note the multiple spaces) would be easier, given that all the different value types are in the same order on each row. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on each line

```
def getTupleFromLine(line):
    l = line.split("   ")[1].split() # ['25399', 'Nov', '2', '21:25', 'exception_hierarchy.pdf'] 
    return (int(l[0]),l[1],int(l[2]),int(l[3]),int(l[4]),l[5])
```

Answer (score 0):

As this seems output from ls -la the order of your information should be static. You can do something like:

```
string = "-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf"
words = string.split()
tupl = (words[4], words[5], words[6], words[7], words[8])
print(tupl)
```

Here the time is 1 word as by default `split()` goes by " ". If you want you can further split it to achieve your exact output.